# What happens when DNS server is set to point to router?

Tags: networking, dns

So, question is in the title. My Windows 10 PC connects to the router. It's DNS is set to my router IP address, not an actual DNS server. So how does my computer get to the DNS server of my ISP?

Comment: A router's WAN-side uses NAT & Masquerade, so the router is acting as the sole WAN-side DNS client for all downstream devices - the router then uses NAT to route those requests correctly back to its clients. The default WAN-side DNS for the router is the ISP unless the user configures their router to use a different WAN-side DNS server, such as OpenDNS, Google, etc. _(generally not recommended to use an ISP's DNS server for privacy reasons, as they often sell data/access to your data, coupled with the ISP, in general, being able to see your DNS queries. DNSSEC should be utilized if available)_

Comment: @jw914 actually, normally not quite. Most routers have a DNS precursor built in. (On typical consumer gear running a Linux variant normally dnsmasq - which also ties in host names). This acts more like a smart caching DNS  proxy then NAT. Dnsmasq or equivalent gets its name servers from the resolved.cinf file, which us typically written by the DHCP client listening on the wan port or equivalent

Comment: @davidgo Right, I was referring to WAN-side DNS requests, which is why I made that specification multiple times since WAN-side DNS is the topic the OP is asking about... AFAIK, none of what I stated is factually inaccurate. As to the LAN-side DNS, often `dnsmasq` is configured to not forward RFC1918 and `localhost` traffic to the WAN-side DNS if it's also serving as the LAN-side DNS server.

Comment: NAT alone doesn't turn the router into a DNS client. Servers _think_ it's the client, but it does not understand the requests nor responses – it only forwards them as UDP packets with opaque payload. (Of course the router's OS has its own client anyway, but it cannot be said that the router acts as a DNS client on behalf of LAN devices unless it actually understands those DNS requests.)

Comment: @JW0914 so even if I set my Windows  PC to use another DNS, it will still go to my ISP DNS?

Comment: @user1686 By default, any router capable of NAT has a DNS client & server built-in, else it wouldn't be a router, it'd be a dumb switch. Routers have to know where to route DNS packets to, else an internet connection is impractical, requiring the physical IP of the site versus the site's hostname. By default, routers get their WAN-side DNS IP from the ISP via DHCP & to override these settings, the router's LAN and/or vLAN interfaces must be configured with a custom DNS IP. If a router isn't acting as the DNS client for downstream devices, how does it know where to route downstream DNS queries?

Comment: @lpydawa It depends on how the router is configured... some routers may honor it, others may not. Why not just change the WAN-side DNS on the router?

Comment: @JW0914: That's complete nonsense. You're maybe assuming that the configuration described by the OP (where computers use the router's IP address as their DNS server) is the _only_ possible configuration? It is not. If the computers were configured to use any other DNS server, then the DNS query packets would be routed **like any other IP packet** without needing any special treatment.

Comment: @user1686 Of course individual devices can have their DNS address set to specific WAN-side DNS server(s), however this isn't the use case for the vast majority of internet users, nor would this apply to my comment, as by **default**, _all routers_ are configured to get their WAN-side DNS via DHCP from the ISP.  With this **default** setup, the router acts as the sole WAN-side DNS client for _all_ downstream devices, unless those devices have been configured w/ custom WAN-side DNS servers _(which isn't what the OP is asking - I can't prove a negative & cover every custom use case in 600 char)_.

Answer (score 7):

Most home routers *are also* actual DNS servers. (Although very basic ones: they usually only support forwarding the queries "upstream" to the ISP's servers, and usually provide some amount of local caching. But that still counts as a "DNS server".)

As many home routers are Linux-based, some of them actually run common DNS relay software such as Unbound or Dnsmasq, although others have custom-made implementations of varying quality.

So when the computer sends the DNS query to your router, the router's internal DNS server first checks if it can be answered from local cache, and if not, forwards it to your ISP's more-capable DNS servers.

(Your computer doesn't really *need* to be talking to the ISP's DNS servers directly, or at all. The DNS responses do not usually contain any ISP-specific information.)